# How to make xindy work with Lualatex?

Tags: luatex, glossaries, xindy

I want to use `glossaries` with `xindy`. If I compile the following MWE with PDFLatex, there is no problem, I get the desired result (screenshot below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage[acronym, automake, xindy]{glossaries-extra}
%\usepackage[acronym, automake=immediate, xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\newacronym{test}{TEST}{This is a test}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{test}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I use LuaLaTeX to compile, I get no result (except the error message below) even after several compilations. Using `automake=immediate` doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Am I missing something? Is there a way to make `xindy` work with LuaLaTeX?

---

**Update by user Manuel Kuehner:** Someone reported the bug, see https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?key=196.

Comment: Which errors? You haven't cited any errors

Comment: Did you look in the log? You still need to allow it to run external programmes via `-shell-escape`. For me xindy complains about missing `.glg` and `.alg` files.

Comment: @daleif my apologies, I wasn't referring to a "real" error, just the text that `glossaries` displays in the output PDF saying that files are missing. Normally I have shell escape enabled, if I use an external software such as GNUplot, I have no problems (neither with PDFLatex nor with LuaLatex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in glossaries. It calls xindy with an empty -C value as the code page is not set:

```
xindy.pl -I xindy -L english -M test-nomgt -C  -t test-nomgt.glg -o test-nomgt.gls test-nomgt.glo
```

Report the bug. As a work around load either fontspec or set the code page manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\usepackage[acronym, automake=immediate, xindy={codepage=utf8}]{glossaries-extra}

\newacronym{test}{TEST}{This is a test}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{test}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wondering, where did you find the actual xindy call?

Comment: @daleif in the log-file.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer, thank you, it works!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer hmm, I might only have looked in the console log