# \xindy.pl: Cannot locate xindy modules directory at c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 409

Tags: texlive, glossaries, xindy

I installed my latex environment on a new laptop (Windows 10, texlive 2022, lualatex, makeglossaries, xindy) and run my, previously working, project.

**Problem:**

When I run makeglossaries invoking xindy, I get the following error in the *.slg or *.alg log files:

```
Failed with error code 2.

Status report:

c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl: Cannot locate xindy modules directory at c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 409.
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
    a5paper,
    fontsize=10pt,
    english,
    ngerman,
    ]{scrbook}
    
\usepackage{babel}  % Sprachen (definiert in Klasse)
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AfterPackage*{hyperref}{%
    \usepackage[%
        nomain,
        xindy={language=german-duden}, % Sortierung nach Duden
        acronym,
        symbols,
        nopostdot,
        shortcuts,
    ]{glossaries}
\newacronym{ADC}{ADC}{Analog-Digital-Converter}
\makeglossaries
}% AfterPackage

\begin{document}

\glsaddallunused
\printacronyms

Using an \gls{ADC}...

\end{document}
```

built with

1. `lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape %.tex`
2. `makeglossaries %`

**from the command line:**

```
***Call to xindy failed*** Check 'xindymoduleserror.alg' for details

C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2: perl c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries xindymoduleserror
```

**What I tried without luck:**

I tried to uninstall and install texlive several times but it did not change the error. (It is a company machine but I have elevated rights and installed texlive from a cmd run as administrator.)

The modules path `C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\xindy\modules` is not empty.

I tried to give the path manually in the xindy.pl script, as suggested by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357285/xindy-pl-cannot-locate-bin-directory-at), but just ran into the next path issue.

Also added these PATH variables (without any change):

```
C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy;
C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\xindy\modules;
C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\xindy\modules\base;
C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\xindy\modules\styles;
```

*I am really puzzled as the setup worked before on the other laptop.
Any help is greatly appreciated!*

Comment: don't less people guess what you are doing exactly. Always show a small but complete example and tell exactly which commands you are using to compile it. That allows other to test if they can reproduce your problem.  Beside this you are running probably in this bug: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633111/2388

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer , sorry I did not include the MWE to begin with. See my update question. As mentioned the code and the pipeline worked before on another machine.
btw, you helped me so much already with all your answers on latex - thank you a lot!

Comment: works okay here. Adding something to the path variable will not help. The question you link to was about the binary not about the modules directory. Also it was a miktex problem. The perl call `Cwd::realpath("$cmd_dir/../../xindy/modules");` seems to fail for you, but this can not be debugged from the outside.

Comment: Is it possible that the installation is faulty because of the way I started the installer? (cmd run as administrator)
Can you give me a hint how I could proceed?